# Azure Service Principal RemoveKey c#

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to remove a certificate to a service account.
I'm doing this with **Microsoft.Graph** *(5.14.0)* with a Service Principal account which is global administrator and has the necessary permissions with Graph.
This master account authenticates via a certificate.

I followed the C# examples like `MicrosoftIdentityPlatformProofTokenGenerator` here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-removekey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-rollkey-prooftoken?tabs=csharp

I systematically get an `Access Token missing or malformed` error... indicating that the problem must surely come from the proof field

```
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.ServicePrincipals.Item.RemoveKey.RemoveKeyPostRequestBody
{
    KeyId = key.KeyId,
    Proof = proof
};

try
{
    await graphClient.ServicePrincipals[sp.Id].RemoveKey.PostAsync(requestBody);
}
catch (ODataError err)
{
    var message = err.Error?.Message;
}
```

From what I understood:

- We create the proof with the object id of the application associated with the principalservice that makes the call (I also tried with the id of the sp).
- We use the certificate of the principalservice to generate a proof token (I use the same certificate as the one with which I identify myself.. and I also tried with the one I want to delete and the identity of the sp but Nothing)
- Or use Microsoft Graph id as audience (it's not very clear but I tried with AAD Graph Api as well)

  - `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` AAD Graph API
  - `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` Microsoft Graph API
- I send the pfxFile (private and public key) to generate the proof

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude..

- If you want to use `removekey` or `addkey` you must use **the local sp application account** with an existing certificate to process to create the proof *(No need to complexify the token with other clams like roles > just `aud` and `iss`)*
- If, like me, you use an external service principal it's not possible to call `removekey` or `addkey` *(or I didn't find good settings but i'm in `Global Administrator`)* => you can use `PATCH` on the SP without any proof...

*...does it really make sense?*

*Microsoft documentations are often not up to date and are much too verbose making their exploitation very laborious...*

Answer (score 0):

I generated the access token and when tried to **`removeKey`**, I got the **error** like below:

[image]

The error "***Access Token missing or malformed***" usually occurs if you are passing invalid access token to perform the action or the **aud** is not matching the access resource.

**To resolve the error**, check the below:

- Check if the **'`=`'** padding character is present in the JWT header or payload, if yes then remove it in order to avoid the `Authentication_MissingOrMalformed` error.

Make sure to grant Admin consent for the **`Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`** like below:

[image]

Decode the token and make sure that the **aud** is `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` or `https://graph.microsoft.com` and required roles are present:

[image]

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.ServicePrincipals.Item.RemoveKey.RemoveKeyPostRequestBody
{
    KeyId = Guid.Parse("f0b0b335-1d71-4883-8f98-567911bfdca6"),
    Proof = "eyJ0eXAiOiJ...",
};
await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["{servicePrincipal-id}"].RemoveKey.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

In the above code, replace the `servicePrincipal-id` by the below value:

[image]

Make sure the access token is not expired or test in Postman using the same token.

After the above changes, **I am able to removeKey successfully via Postman** like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/removeKey
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "keyId": "KeyID",
    "proof":"Token."
}
```

[image]